# Что мне написать в else, что бы он вернул меня к input

Tags: python

```
w = input("да/нет: ")
if w == "да":
    print("Рад это слышать")
elif w == "нет":
    print("не рад, это слышать!")
else:
```

Comment: Ничего, нужно писать цикл

Comment: Всё это заверни в бесконечный цикл, и если ответ удовлетворяет, то выход из цикла.

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсия

```
def Def():
    w = input("да/нет: ")
    if w == "да":
        print("Рад это слышать")
    elif w == "нет":
        print("не рад, это слышать!")
    else:
        Def()
Def()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    w = input("да/нет: ")
    if w == "да":
        print("Рад это слышать")
        break
    else:
        print("не рад, это слышать!")
```

можно ещё условие для чего-то неправильно введённого дописать, в данном случае, если ввести что-нибудь неправильное, сработает блок else. ещё, неплохо бы input завернуть в lower(), для возможности ввода в любом регистре...

Comment: Спасибо большое